# How can I resolve crashing on `DateTime.parse "Feb. 29"`?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I parse text dates and will be returned a `DateTime` like this:

```
DateTime.parse "Feb. 28"
# => Sat, 28 Feb 2015 00:00:00 +0000
```

However, parsing `"Feb. 29"` causes an invalid date crash. How can I resolve this crash to account for this leap year date?

Comment: Since you aren't passing a year, it defaults to using the current year.  Since there is  no Feb 28th in 2015, it's an invalid date.  If you pass it a year `DateTime.parse("Feb. 29 2016")` you'll get a valid return

Comment: @trh is there a way to catch exception in ruby/rails?

Comment: This is the funniest error I've ever seen. So it'll work for a year and then fail the next 3 and then work for a year again? ;)

Comment: Ya, this is zany behavior - I posted a rescue answer - but it stinks for most applications.

Comment: How do you want to handle this exception? Just return `nil` or the next day? What do you think is appropriate in your use case?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if the year is a leap year or not using [leap?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-leap-3F) method:

```
Date.leap? 2016 # => true
Date.leap? 2015 # => false
```

So, if it's a leap year, you can pass the year along with the date i.e. `DateTime.parse "Feb. 29 2016"`. That way, your program will not crash.

Or, you can just use the date along with year always to avoid such cases. i.e. `DateTime.parse "Feb. 28 2013"` and `DateTime.parse "Feb. 29 2016"` etc. If you pass your dates in this format, then you don't have to check for leap year explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You *CAN* capture exceptions raised while parsing an invalid date..

```
begin
  d = DateTime.parse("Feb. 29")
rescue ArgumentError  
  d = "Invalid Date"
end
```

But it's probably not ideal, and really just depends on what you're doing with the data as to the best way to proceed.  If you're looking for a complete date object it might be better to do something like checking for the leap year of a given datetime object and proceeding from there.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - quite so, the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` object (or a date in the ordinary sense) cannot be defined by just month and day; it needs the year. As you may have noticed by parsing `"Feb. 28"`, omitting the year indicates that the string is to be parsed as the current year. The string `"Feb. 29"` is not rejected unconditionally, but is rejected particularly at this time since this year (2015) is not a leap year, hence `"Feb. 29"` is not valid.

So the solution is, whenever you are parsing a string to be evaluated as the current year, it works correctly as is; `"Feb. 29"` would be rejected correctly if the current year is not a leap year. Otherwise, you need to provide an explicit year.

K M Rakibul Islam's answer is on the right track for mentioning explicit year should be provided, but that answer is wrong regarding when to do so.

Comment: Hi, could you please point out which part was wrong in my answer `but that answer is wrong regarding when to do so.` (I edited my answer a bit after your answer though). But, I am not sure which part you indicated. I would appreciate if you could explain it a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam Please do not edit your answer following my comment since that would mean you are copying my answer to yours. In fact, that is the reason I wrote about it in my answer, not as a comment to yours. I do not intend to have my answer/comment reflected in your answer. As I wrote, error raised with Feb. 29 is the correct behavior if the omitted year is not a leap year. A date cannot exist without a year (implicit or explicit), and Feb. 29 does not exist for a non-leap year. Omission of a year should not be conditioned depending on whether the current year is a leap year or not.

Comment: Here is my edit revision: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32388973/revisions
Feel free to edit this again if you think anything is copied from your answer there. Thank you.